# Scala println in a for loop

Tags: scala, printing, println

The following Scala code does just what I expect it to - it prints each line of some_file.txt.

```
import scala.io.Source
val lines = Source.fromPath("some_file.txt").mkString
for (line <- lines) print(line)
```

If I use println instead of print, I expect to see some_file.txt printed out with double-spacing.  Instead, the program prints a newline after every character of some_file.txt.  Could someone explain this to me?  I'm using Scala 2.8.0 Beta 1.

Answer (score 23):

`lines` is a single string, not some iterable container of strings. This is because you called the `.mkString` method on it.

When you iterate over a string, you do so one character at a time. So the `line` in your `for`  is not actually a line, it's a single character.

What you probably intended to do was call `.getLines` instead of `.mkString`

Comment: He called `.mkString` on the result of `fromPath`, which is an `Iterator[Char]` with some added stuff. I know you know this, but I think you could make it clearer. You could also put an example of a for comprehension over a `String` literal.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `for (line <- lines) print(line)` doesn't put a line in `line` but instead a character. Making the output as expected since the `\n` is there too. When you the replace the `print` with `println` every character gets its own line.